# from a PDF, extract highlights with page numbers from the command line (Linux)

Tags: linux, pdf

Is there a way to extract, from a PDF, the highlighted passages *with the corresponding page numbers* from the command line, on Linux? I found two tools, but they do not exactly fit my needs: [pdf-highlights-extractor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfhex/) allows me to extract the highlighted passages with the page numbers, but it does not have a command line interface, only a graphical interface. And [DyAnnotationExtractor](https://github.com/dimi2/DyAnnotationExtractor) has a command line interface, but only gives me the highlighted passages, not the page numbers. Is there a tool that can do what I need?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you need a command line interface so that you can parse the output? or maybe to call it from scripts?

Comment: @golimar: Both: I would like to call the command from a script and then further process the output.

Comment: For the first option, many times Java GUI applications look GUI only but they also support command line arguments. Or you could call the Java class that processes the PDF file instead of calling the GUI class.

Comment: As a last resort, since both options are hosted in open source sites, you can open a ticket or issue asking for that feature, or check the source code to see if you can modify it

Comment: @golimar: Thank you for the suggestions! I have already contacted the author of `pdf-highlights-extractor`. He told me that the software does not support command line arguments and that no such support is planned for the future. I will now contact the author of `DyAnnotationExtractor` and ask whether the option of including the page numbers in the output could be added as a feature.

Comment: Are you interested in some custom Python or Go code to handle this? I've got some solutions in Python and Go.

Comment: @ZachYoung: Would I be able to use this code without knowing Python or Go? (My programming experience is limited to XSLT, PHP and Bash.)

Comment: You'll need to know something about installing dependencies for either. Post comments on my answer below if you get stuck with anything. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Full disclosure: I'm being paid as a consultant by UniDOC/UniPDF to answer this question and spread good will towards PDFs, Go, and UniPDF.*

I've written two command-line programs that are equivalent. They both read some number of PDFs that you list, locate highlighted text per page, and then print out CSV of the PDF, page number, and the highlighted text.

For both the PyMuPDF (Python) and the UniPDF (Go) code examples, I'll use these two reference PDFs:

|  | one_page.pdf | two_pages.pdf |
| --- | --- | --- |
| page 1 | [image] | [image] |
| page 2 |  | [image] |

[main.py](https://github.com/zacharysyoung/extract_highlighted_text/blob/main/main.py)

```
./main.py one_page.pdf two_pages.pdf 
Filename,Page_num,Highlighted_text
one_page.pdf,1,word1
one_page.pdf,1,d2 word3 wo
two_pages.pdf,1,"“and what is the use of a book,” thought Alice “without pictures or conversations?”"
two_pages.pdf,2,when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.
```

and

[main.go](https://github.com/zacharysyoung/extract_highlighted_text/blob/main/main.go)

```
go run main.go one_page.pdf two_pages.pdf 
Filename,Page_num,Highlighted_text
one_page.pdf,1,word1
one_page.pdf,1,d2 word3 wor
two_pages.pdf,1,"“and what is the use of a book,” thought Alice “without pictures or conversations?”"
two_pages.pdf,2,when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.
```

The Python program uses the PyMuPDF library, which is being actively maintained and updated. Consult the docs for getting the library installed, [PyMuPDF: Installation](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

The Go program uses the UniPDF library, which has a freemium tier where 100 document reads/writes are free per month:

- You can run the program here to get a feel for it, [UniPDF Playground: extract highlighted text in PDF](https://play.unidoc.io/p/c7d7e7f44265f889).
- You can see how to get a free account, create an API key, and start using it here, [How To Set Metered License Key For UniDoc Products](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzazZH55te4).

Both programs also have a VISUALIZE switch in the source code that you can turn on to visualize what the highlight rectangles look like, which can be very handy if you ever start getting weird results. The highlights don't contain the text, they're just graphical objects that are drawn **over** text. Both programs get the highlight rectangles, then use other APIs in their respective libraries to query a page for text *in the rectangle*, but the different libraries have different ideas about what text is inside or outside of a particular highlighted region (rectangle):

- For PyMuPDF I had to grow the highlight rectangle just ever so slightly to get any text.
- For UniPDF I had to shrink the highlight rectangle vertically, and substantially, to avoid extraneous text (outside of the intended highlight region).

If you're new to using Go, you can [download Go](https://go.dev/dl/) for your system (Linux) and then you can run the program interactively with `go run main.go pdf1 ...`, or you can build an executable and install it on your path and then call it like any command-line utility:

```
go build -o listhltext main.go
cp listhltext [SOMEWHERE ON YOUR PATH]
```

Comment: I tried the Python program. I first installed `PyMuPDF`. Now, when I try the Python program on a file (like so: `python3.7 main.py test.pdf`), I get the following error message: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 27, in <module> annot: fitz.Annot = page.firstAnnot AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'firstAnnot'`. What is going wrong? (Edit: I get the same error message when I run the program on your test file `one_page.pdf`.)

Comment: Change that to `page.first_annot`... you got a newer version of PyMuPDF than me. I'll work to update it this weekend.

Comment: Now the program works, thank you! I tested it on 3 PDFs and compared the results to `pdf-highlights-extractor`. On the first PDF (a book), the program works beautifully and more accurately (as for the extracted text) than `p-h-e`. But on the other two PDFs (a book and a paper), the program does not work at all: it outputs only the page numbers of the highlights but not the text. `p-h-e` does not work perfectly either on these PDFs (there are many extra spaces and tabs in the extracted text), but at least it does output the highlighted text. What might be the problem?

Comment: I cannot even begin to guess, I'm new to this and simply don't have enough experience. Will you edit your question and include both a good sample (the book) and a bad sample (the book, the paper)? (Share from Google Drive?) I can definitely take a look and try both programs for myself.

Comment: Oh, try adjusting the SCALE_H and SCALE_W constants. If you’re getting no text, the highlight rectangle might be too small. Change those values to 2.0, just to prove you can get some text, then dial them back down till you get the correct text.

Comment: I fixed `page.first_annot` and added command-line args to the Python prog. Do a `git pull` or re-download the project. Now, you'll need to supply the scale factors with `--scale-w` and `--scale-h`. I used `1.001` and `1.001` to get the Alice text correct. You'll need to play around with those values for different PDFs (because there's no standard that says how the overlayed rectangle relates to the text underneath it).

Comment: Thank you! As you suggested, I played around with the `SCALE_X` and `SCALE_Y` values. I found that I could leave the `X` value at 1.0 and modify only the `Y` value. I found the following: PDF1 worked with the original value (as already mentioned). PDF2 required 1.2. PDF3 required 1.6. So I will now use the program with 1.6 and see whether this value works for all my PDFs.

Comment: One more thing: I noticed that sometimes (i.e., in some results) the extracted text is wrapped in quotation marks, but sometimes not. Why is that, and can this behavior be controlled (e.g., omit the quotation marks in all cases)?

Comment: I think you’re seeing CSV quoting, and that’s not part of the actual result. When you open the CSV in a spreadsheet app do you still see extraneous quotes?

Comment: You are right. I noticed that the quotation marks appear when the extracted text contains a comma. When I open the results with LibreOffice Calc, the quotation marks are not displayed.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend usage of the nifty little Python library [pdfannots](https://github.com/0xabu/pdfannots), which has the very capability you are looking for.

```
$ pdfannots sample.pdf
```

If combined with some other Bash commands, it can produce nicely formatted output. For example:

```
$ pdfannots sample.pdf --no-condense | \
# Removing duplicate lines:
cat -n | sort -uk2 | sort -nk1 | cut -f2- | \
# Improving output formatting:
awk '{$1=$1};1' | sed 's/^\(> \)//g' | sed 's/* Page #/\n&/'
```